# Format array of values into a concatenated string using Spark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe `sdf` with millions of rows that contain GPS coordinates:

```
+------------------+-------------------+------+
|          latitude|          longitude|radius|
+------------------+-------------------+------+
| 37.75243634842733|-122.41924881935118|    10|
| 37.75344580658182|-122.42006421089171|    10|
| 37.75405656449232|  -122.419216632843|    10|
|37.753649393112184|-122.41784334182738|    10|
| 37.75409897804892| -122.4169099330902|    10|
|37.753937806404586|-122.41549372673035|    10|
| 37.72767062183685| -122.3878937959671|    10|
| 37.72710631810977| -122.3884356021881|    10|
| 37.72605407110467|-122.38841414451599|    10|
| 37.71141865080228|-122.44688630104064|    10|
|37.712199505873926|-122.44474053382874|    10|
|37.713285899241896|-122.44361400604248|    10|
| 37.71428740401767|-122.44260549545288|    10|
|37.712810604103346|-122.44156479835509|    10|
| 37.75405656449232| -122.4169099330902|    10|
|37.753649393112184|-122.41549372673035|    10|
+------------------+-------------------+------+
```

I would like to format the lat lon values as a concatenated string (separated by a semicolon) so that I can feed these coordinates to an (OSRM) request. I am able to achieve this by:

```
# 1. Converting spark df to pandas df
pdf = sdf.toPandas()

# 2. Setting coordinates
coords = pdf[['latitude', 'longitude']].values
coords

# 3. Formatting NumPy array of (lat, long) coordinates into a concatenated string formatted for the OSRM server
def format_coords(coords: np.ndarray) -> str:
    coords = ";".join([f"{lon:f},{lat:f}" for lat, lon in coords])
    return coords

format_coords(coords)

# 4. Desired output:
'-122.419249,37.752436;-122.420064,37.753446;-122.419217,37.754057;-122.417843,37.753649;-122.416910,37.754099;-122.415494,37.753938;-122.387894,37.727671;-122.388436,37.727106;-122.388414,37.726054;-122.446886,37.711419;-122.444741,37.712200;-122.443614,37.713286;-122.442605,37.714287;-122.441565,37.712811;-122.416910,37.754057;-122.415494,37.753649'
```

Although this works for smaller datasets, this workflow (especially converting a pandas to a Spark dataframe) takes ages. Is there a solution to read in the coordinates directly from a Spark dataframe without having to convert it to pandas first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate the dataframe as below:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

output = df.agg(
    F.concat_ws(';', 
        F.collect_list(
            F.format_string('%f,%f', 'longitude', 'latitude')
        )
    )
).head()[0]

print(output)
# '-122.419249,37.752436;-122.420064,37.753446;-122.419217,37.754057;-122.417843,37.753649;-122.416910,37.754099;-122.415494,37.753938;-122.387894,37.727671;-122.388436,37.727106;-122.388414,37.726054;-122.446886,37.711419;-122.444741,37.712200;-122.443614,37.713286;-122.442605,37.714287;-122.441565,37.712811;-122.416910,37.754057;-122.415494,37.753649'
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution but on a different column called `radius` which contains a value of 10 for all rows. My desired output is the same (i.e. 10;10;10;10...). However, `output = sdf.agg(
    F.concat_ws(';', 
        F.collect_list(
            F.format_string('%f', 'radius')
        )
    )
).head()[0]` returns an error. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have another different question, please kindly open another question @sampeterson

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question here.

Comment: I updated the spark dataframe in my question. It now has a column radius, populated with values of 10. I would like to achieve exactly the same type output (i.e. a concatenated string separated by semicolons: 10;10;10;10 etc.) but got an error with the code above

Comment: @sampeterson  10 is not a float - you need to use `%d` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [resilient distributed dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) to do this, I'm not sure how performant this will be in your case:

```
sdf2 = sdf.rdd.map(lambda x: f"{x.longitude},{x.latitude}")
print(";".join(sdf2.collect()))
```

When I run this on an example with just a few rows it returns:

```
-122.41924881935118,37.75243634842733;-122.42006421089171,37.75344580658182[...}
```

Comment: It uses parallel operations to do the concatenation of `longitude` & `latitude` and then collects the results from the resulting rdd data frame.